# How to modify media audio in SurfaceView?

Tags: android, audio, surfaceview

I have a doubt with media audio.

My app haves an Activity which loads a SurfaceView class and I cannot get to modify media audio.

I saw the following statement :

```
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

but it isn't works.

¿Someone could help me?

Thanks!

EDIT SOME CODE:

In my first Activity for example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
//Other things
}
```

I'm trying to modify multimedia audio stream in runtime, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: Where do you set setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); ?

Comment: I set this code into onCreate method in my Activity. Before this Activiy I have 2 other Activities and also isn't work.

Comment: Okay, it should work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That should do it, I've made mine the same way, but not with this.setVolumeControlStream, try removing this. but actually it should do the same.

Comment: Where do you set your SurfaceView?

Comment: I do this to create mi SurfaceView into onCreate on my Activity:
gameViewTour = new GameViewTour(this,handler);
setContentView(gameViewTour);
I have tried setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);  but it isn't works. 
I tried to create an instance of AudioManager and do this
am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
         am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)-1, 0);
and it works fine

Comment: Okey, I'm glad it works, but very strang though. It should work as you did before. Anyways, good luck with your game ;)

Comment: I have a little problem, my new solution works in my HTC Wildfire but don't works in Samsung Galaxy Mini.  Someone could say me a solution please?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, try this. I managed to do it on my SurfaceView.
In your Activity you have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this, GameActivity.this);
    setContentView(gameView); 
}
```

Then in your SurfaceView you can do the followin in the constructor:

```
public GameView(Context context, Activity activity) {
    super(context);
    activity.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}
```